# First installation

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, display, wifi

I have a lot of question before my first installation of a linux distribution.
For my next job (i'll start in 1 month), i'll use a computer (with Linux). So i'll try to learn to use it before i start my job.

So, i've search somes informations and i see we have a lot of distribution. I've choose Elementary OS (for the user interface).

I have this components :

1. Intel core I5 760 - 2.80ghZ
2. NVIDIA Geforce GTX 460
3. USB Wifi - Netgear wma3100m

So, i'll add a hard drive in my computer, i'll use the first for Windows 10 and the second for Elementary OS.

So, i want to know if my computer is compatible with Elementary OS (with my I5-Geforce-USB Wifi Dongle).

Thanks.

Comment: You should try y a live session to confirm your hardware works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u will not have problem with CPU and GPU, after installing, install the drivers from App Center, I really recommend this
Wifi, only testing, but I have a USB wifi from China and it works, probably it's gonna work too

Answer (score 0):

i m using elementary os 0.4.1 loki with a bad pc than yours

- Dual-Core Pentium® Dual-Core CPU       T4500  @ 2.30GHz Intel
- Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
- RAM: 4 GB

and everything works perfectly , i run firefox (more than 8 tabs), atom, hexchat, terminals, Gimp, and scripts ... at the same time and it works without any bugs (it's like if i have the best pc)

wifi works with netgear and other adapters

i dont know ur RAM but i think it will works without any problem